# MSSQL 2008 r2 Express: there is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-usage, virtual-memory, sql-server-express

I'm experiencing this error during the lifecycle of my DotNetNuke Installation. I've change the hosting server and now I've got a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 an SQL server 2008 r2 Express running on the same machine: 64bit, 12GB di RAM.

The site works perfectly for 4 or 5 hours until when, randomly, start giving in SQL Express Log the above error and then the instance database accept no more connections.

If I do an IIS reset, sql server release the memory and all works great again!

How could it be?

Thanks in advance!

I'll put here some log entries if they could be of any help:

```
2015-03-24 19:05:26.01 spid15767   Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 89.
2015-03-24 19:05:26.01 spid15767   There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
2015-03-24 19:05:26.03 spid15767   Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 29. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:35.20 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:35.20 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:35.20 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:35.20 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:35.20 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:40.21 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2015-03-24 19:05:45.75 spid15773   Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 123.
2015-03-24 19:05:45.75 spid15773   There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
Memory Manager                                   KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                12651576
VM Committed                                1529500
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
Reserved Memory                                1024
Reserved Memory In Use                            0
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
Memory node Id = 0                               KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                12650488
VM Committed                                1528472
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
MultiPage Allocator                           23840
SinglePage Allocator                        1371672
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (node 0)                  KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                       0
VM Committed                                      0
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
SM Reserved                                       0
SM Committed                                      0
SinglePage Allocator                          15536
MultiPage Allocator                            3824
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL (node 0)               KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                12615680
VM Committed                                1495168
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
SM Reserved                                       0
SM Committed                                      0
SinglePage Allocator                              0
MultiPage Allocator                             400
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 0)                KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                       0
VM Committed                                      0
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
SM Reserved                                       0
SM Committed                                      0
SinglePage Allocator                             48
MultiPage Allocator                               0
2015-03-24 19:06:01.24 spid3s      
MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER (node 0)                KB
```

Comment: Due to the possiblity ofa bug (as per answer) - can you provide the exact build number? (of your SQL Server version). Is it possible to - update to a newer SQL Server express, they are free anyway.

Comment: My SQL Server 2008 r2 versione is 10.50.6000.34

Comment: Then I would consider moving to a newer version. Regardless how you turn it, 2008 R2 is ancient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made all windows update on my Windows Server 2012 and I moved to MSSql Server 2014 Express.

Now all works great!

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that this is [a bug in SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982854):

> When you run a Full-Text query that uses compound words in Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2008 or in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, you receive the
>   following error message in the Error log file:
>
> Date Time spidID Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 123.
>
> Date Time spidID There is insufficient system memory in resource pool
>   'internal' to run this query.
>
> Additionally, if you run a Full-Text query successfully after this
>   problem occurs, you receive the same error message.
>
> This problem occurs for all the following reasons:
>
> - There is a bug in the code that is used to evaluate how many rowsets are required to perform a sorting operation. Therefore, the
>     code greatly overestimates the numbers of rowsets. The required grant
>     estimate in full-text is 64 pages for each rowset that is required to
>     sort.
> - There is a large request that blocks the system from using the memory that is reserved for the full-text query.

It looks like some modules of DotNetNuke may use full text.

Comment: Thanks, I've check my build version and I think It's newer. Ain't it? My SQL Server 2008 r2 versione is 10.50.6000.34

Comment: That's SP3;  this was apparently cumulative update 4 for SP2, so I assume KB 2345451 is included.